# How to aggregate bower assets by their absolute path in Mean IO

Tags: node.js, bower, mean-stack, bower-install, mean.io

Project is based on Mean IO stack. Installing bower dependencies installs them to `/bower_components`, how can I access those when aggregating assets? I know I can specify location where files should be installed to, but I need that folder to be accessible from every package.

Currently working solution is, which looks a bit odd to me:

```
Package.aggregateAsset('js', '../../../../../../bower_components/dep/file.js');
```

And another question, if I have to pages in package, and I want them to use different assets, what would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
Package.aggregateAsset('js', '../../../../../../bower_components/dep/file.js', {global: true});
```

Answer (score 0):

At the root of your theme's package, create a .bowerrc file with the following content:

```
{
  "directory": "public/assets/lib"
}
```

Bower will now install the libs in `packages/custom/yourThemePackage/public/assets/lib` and you can now aggregate your files from `yourThemePackage/app.js` like this:

```
YourThemePackage.aggregateAsset('css', '../lib/someLib/css/someStyle.min.css');
YourThemePackage.aggregateAsset('js', '../lib/someLib/js/someScript.min.js');
```